# Unsolvable host comparison script

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurl, wkwebview

I'm trying to create a script that compares dynamically websites on the internet and figures out if they are of the same root or not.

Example:

A. "apple.com" and "itunes.apple.com" are of the same root "apple.com"

B. "apple.com.gr" and "apple.com" are not of the same root.

What makes this unsolvable is the presence of [SLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain).

Here's what I mean:

Assume that you are trying to compare two host strings separated by the component "."

Before separation:

```
"itunes.apple.com"
```

After separation:

```
"itunes" . "apple" . "com"
```

1. You get a match at the first component.

This means absolutely nothing because it could be anything.

"google" . "com" and "apple" . "com" share the same first component "com".

2. You get a match at the first and second component.

This means that either (A) you have two websites that share the same root or that (B) a SLD is present.

A. "apple" . "com" and "itunes" . "apple" . "com" have the same root "apple.com"

B. "google" . "com" . "gr" and "facebook" . "com" . "gr" share the same SLD.

The only way to solve this is by knowing the list of all SLDs and that is just ugly.

**EDIT:**

COMPARISON A

"**apple**" . "co" . "uk"

"**yahoo**" . "co" . "uk"

COMPARISON B

"ftp" . "**acme**" . "org"

"sql" . "**acme**" . "org"

I can't think of a script that will result in identifying that the domains are of different roots in comparison A and of the same root in comparison B WITHOUT knowing that "co.uk" is a SLD.

Comment: You can try to take leftmost component from the TLD. In case of `itunes.apple.com.gr` you take leftmost component from `.com` which is `apple`. The same goes for example for uk ebay - `ebay.co.uk`, it this case `co` is TLD so you take leftmost piece - `ebay`.

Comment: When you compare "itunes.apple.com" and "apple.com" the leftmost component after the rightmost 2-component match is NULL.

Comment: You should design the script thay way so it searches TLD in both `itunes.apple.com` and `apple.com` it will be `com` and take component that is left from this TLD component.

Comment: Take a look at the added comparisons.